# How to send custom message before, proxy session send actual message

Tags: php, proxy, twilio

When Customer replies to proxy service reserved number then proxy hit an OutOfSessionCallbackUrl(if a session is not active).
That URL will come to my code below.

```
 public function response()
 {
    $to = $_POST['To'];
    $from = $_POST['From'];
    $from = substr($from, 2);
    $body = $_POST['Body'];
    $twilio = new Client($this->sid, $this->token);

    $response=$this->db->get_where('contact_management as cm 
    ,proxy_service as ps',
   array('mobile'=>$from,'company_mobile'=>$to,'sc.sms_template_id<>'=>0))
    ->row_array();
    $number = trim($response['country_code'].$response['mobile_number']);

    //Here I'm sending a response
        header("content-type:application/json");
        ?>
        {
        "uniqueName": "<?php echo rand();?>",
        "ttl":"64800",
        "mode": "voice-and-message",
        "participantIdentifier":"<?php echo $number;?>"
        }
        <?php
}
```

This will create a session between SMS sender and returned number(company) and send the message of the sender to the company. I want to send a custom message before Twilio proxy send actual message to the company.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the regular [Twilio Messaging API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) to send your custom message?

Comment: If i use messaging API then company will get both message from different number, 1 from  messaging api number and second from proxy pool number.

Comment: So use the proxy service to send the message too?

Comment: when OutOfSessionCallbackUrl is call, my code return an array with proxyIdentifier after that proxy will automatically select the number from the number pool to send the message, so how can i send message.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently you are using [the out of session callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/out-session-callback-response-guide) in order to create a session, but you want to send a message before you forward on the incoming message.

To do this, you won't be able to respond with the JSON to create a session. Instead, you should [create the session manually using the session API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/session#create-a-session-resource). Once you have created a session you can then send your initial message by [creating an interaction on the participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/sending-messages) you want to send the message to. You can then follow up by using the same API to forward the original message. And finally you still need to respond to the webhook. Since you handled all the message sending manually, you can return an empty TwiML `<Response/>` to signify that you need Twilio to take no further part.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: i have used this technique earlier, let me tell you what is the drawback is when the customer replies to the reserved proxy number it will create a session and add both participants (customer and company). The company will get an incoming message from the new proxy number. That is OK when the company reply to that proxy number than the customer will get that response from new proxy number2. not from the reserved number.

Comment: Hey evangelist,Thank you. Only one thing is left in my code is, when adding customer as participant i have to set proxyIdentifier as Twilio reserved number. that's it. My problem is Solved Hurreyyyy

Answer (score 0):

Here Are the complete Description.
I have add Twilio number as reserved in proxy service and set the proxy service OutOfSessionCallbackUrl.When this URL reach my code then the magic happens,

```
   public function response()
   {
    $to = $_POST['To'];
    $from = $_POST['From'];
    $twilio = new Client($this->sid, $this->token);
    $response=$this->db->get_where('contact_management ,proxy_service,
     array('mobile'=>$from,'company_mobile'=>$to))->row_array();

        $service_sid=$response['service_sid'];

        $session = $twilio->proxy->v1->services($service_sid)->sessions
            ->create(array("uniqueName" => rand(),"ttl"=>"64800"));
        $session_sid = $session->sid;

        $participant1 = $twilio->proxy->v1->services($service_sid)
        ->sessions($session_sid)->participants->create($_POST['From'], // identifier
             array("friendlyName" => $response['f_name'],"proxyIdentifier"=>$to));
            $from_id = $participant1->proxyIdentifier;

        $participant2 = $twilio->proxy->v1->services($service_sid)
        ->sessions($session_sid)->participants
        ->create($response['country_code'].$response['mobile_number'], // identifier
           array("friendlyName" => $response['first_name']));
        $to_id = $participant2->proxyIdentifier;
        $to_sid = $participant2->sid;


        $body   =   $response['campaign_name']."\n";
        $body   .=  $_POST['Body'];
        $message_interaction = $twilio->proxy->v1->services($service_sid)
                                     ->sessions($session_sid)
                                     ->participants($to_sid)
                                     ->messageInteractions
                                     ->create(array("body" => $body));


        header("content-type:text/xml");
        ?>
        <Response />
        <?php
     }
```